# Getting System.IO.IOException in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, httprequest

i try to make an HTTP POST to an Swagger UI api and wrote this rudimentary Code:

```
        string baseip = "192.168.0.1";
        string auth = "authcodre";
        string name = "TestMan";
        string ip = "1.1.1.1";
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        string URL = "https://" + baseip + ":4444/api/objects/network/host/";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("token:" + auth));
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string patchtxt = "{  \"name\": \"" + name + "\",  \"_type\": \"network/host\",  \"address\": \"" + ip + "\"}";
            streamWriter.Write(patchtxt);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Patches");
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8); //Einlesen der HTTP-Antwort
            string resppatch = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(resppatch);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It throws me an System.IO.IOException" in mscorlib.dll at this line: 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: What does the message of the Exception say?

Comment: It sasys exactly this:

Comment: Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.IO.IOException" in mscorlib.dll
Patches

Comment: Try: `HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL); `. Better still, wrap your code in a try block,and catch the `Exception`.

Comment: I I tried this and catched the Exception but it still says the same :)

Comment: This error seems very generic, Is there any InnerException inside exception?